# Opencv Subdiv2d (Delaunay Triangulation) remove vertices at infinity

Tags: opencv, triangulation, delaunay

I am using subdiv2d class of opencv for delaunay triangulation. I am particularly facing the problem with vertices at infinity. I do not need any triangle outside the image. So, I inserted the corner points of the image which works nice in many cases. But in certain cases, I still have triangles outside the image. So, I want to remove those vertices at infinity. Any help regarding removing the vertices or any other way, someone can suggest so that the triangles are always within the image?

Here is the code for inserting feature points in subdiv. I have inserted the corner points of the image.

```
    Mat img  = imread(...);
    Rect rect(0, 0, 600, 600);
    Subdiv2D subdiv(rect);

    // inserting corners of the image
    subdiv.insert( Point2f(0,0));
    subdiv.insert( Point2f(img.cols-1, 0));
    subdiv.insert( Point2f(img.cols-1, img.rows-1));
    subdiv.insert( Point2f(0, img.rows-1));

    // inserting N feature points
    // ...

    // further processing
```

Here is an example where corner points at infinity are creating problem

5 feature points, one in the middle and 4 corners
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VONsN.jpg

5 feature points, one near the bottom and 4 corner points
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjxgm.jpg

You can see in the 2nd image that triangle is outside the image

Comment: [Code is always welcome!](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Berriel I have edited and also provided an example when the problem is there.